# How to import a set of users into CQ/AEM without asking them to login for the first time into CQ

Tags: adobe, aem

I have a requirement where, users (with company username and password) should be available in CQ. We have configured LDAP to authenticate the user on the CQ instance based on his company username and password. But, currently, what is happening is, by default, that user is not present in the list of users we see in CQ. Only after he logs in to CQ instance for the first time, his user profile is getting added to the list of users. Is there a way to create/import all the list of users that we have in the company into CQ without asking them to login??? Basically, I should be able to see all the list of users that we have in the company without asking them to login to the CQ instance. Which means, we should be able to import them.
Or, is the scenario above is invalid, since users are being added as and when we login to the CQ instance. I am a bit unclear about this scenario, so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

CQ provides different ways to achieve this,

- Manual synchronization of users using felix console.
- Using CURL
- Creating JMX client that uses LDAP MBean

I am putting the first way to achieve this, you may refer to the [link](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/how-to-synchronize-user-with-ldap.html) for the detailed answer:

Manual synchronization of users using felix console.

- Open the felix jmx console and log in as admin at http://:/system/console/jmx
- Click on domain com.adobe.granite.ldap and it displays list of
  attributes and operations that can be performed.
- Click on operations and pops up with small window to supply parameter
  (if required). Ex:- syncUser operation, supply the DN of the single
  user (cn=user001,ou=users,dc=day,dc=com) to be synchronized
- Click Invoke to transfer appropriate details from the ldap directory
  server to CRX.